# How do you use " let newSwiftColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 165, blue: 0, alpha: 0)?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I am writing an app where a button has a border with the hex color of #22A7EF. In the viewDidLoad section, I tried to set the colors of the borders like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from  a nib.
    animalNumber.delegate = self
    weightInKilos.delegate = self
    percentOfDehydration.delegate = self
    ongoingLosses.delegate = self
    factor.delegate = self

    let newSwiftColor = UIColor(red: 34, green: 167, blue: 239, alpha: 0)

    calcbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    calcbutton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    calcbutton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.newSwiftColor().CGColor
}
```

I think that is the correct way to declare a color variable, but how am I supposed to use the variable in the `calcbutton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.newSwiftColor().CGColor` part? Xcode says for the line of code I just showed that "type UIColor has no member newSwiftColor". I think I am implementing the variable incorrectly. Does anybody know or see what I did wrong? Thanks!

**PS-** Before you comment or answer, please know that

- I am a 12 year old that learned everything I know about programming online
- I have looked through many articles on the web (including Stack Overflow), but I do not understand any of the answers :(
  Thanks!

Comment: `newSwiftColor.CGColor`

Comment: I tried taking out the `()` and the `UIColor` bit, but it didn't work. The only thing that happened is that when I tapped the button, the app crashed.

Comment: So `newSwiftColor.CGColor` can compile, right? The crash happens when you tap the button, so it is an unrelated issue. Please show us your code that is executed when the button is tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating a new variable that contains a reference to a UIColor (`newSwiftColor`), it would just be:

```
calcbutton.layer.borderColor = newSwiftColor.CGColor
```

Note that Colors in UIKit are specified using floats from 0..1 not ints from 0..255, so you need to divide all your RGB values by 255.0:

```
let newSwiftColor = UIColor(red: 34.0/255.0, green: 167.0/255.0, blue: 239.0/255.0, alpha: 0)
```